# Smile! Just smile

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

It's well known that **Brainf*ck** is very bad at Kolmogorov-complexity problems, for example, it requires around 100 characters just to print "Hello world".

However, there might be texts where Brainf*ck is just very good at.

Your task is now to write a program that takes no input, and it displays the following:

```
☺
```

That is, a smiley face (ASCII 1, if you browser does not render it).

Brainf*ck can do it in 2 characters.

```
+.
```

**Try to find a language that beats it!**

We assume your console can actually display that character (or your font has it, etc.).

Shortest code wins. If there are more of the same length, the first wins, but I'll upvote the others as well.

**EDIT:** I'm very sorry, I did not think the first post arrives this soon. A quick edit: the language has to be Turing-complete!

Comment: I must dispute your description of the output: While your code really outputs a character with the binary code 1, it is not ASCII-encoded, but belongs to some DOS codepage encoding like CP850 or CP437. In any modern console the smiley will not appear, because modern == UTF-8. ☺

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of Hello World, because the string to output is so short, so the task is essentially "how short is it to output any string"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### FALSE (2)

```
1,
```

All that reading about BF paid off! False is an ancestor of Brainfuck.

Comment: Ouch! Strange that no one thought of this until now. :)

Comment: I had to accept this one, as the versions with plain-text and html were not actually done with programming languages.

Comment: I tried to do it with BLC, but I can't make any sense out of BLC. And even a 1-state Turing machine needs 4 or 5 elements in the tuple.

Answer (score 8):

### C, 18 chars

Far from beating Brainf**k, but as good as C can get (I guess).
Only works on little-endian platforms, must run without parameters.

```
main(c){puts(&c);}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Micronetics System MUMPS 4.4 (7 chars)

```
w $c(1)
```

Comment: MUMPS? Oh, the horror... I never even imagined that I'll see it here. +1 just for the pure shock value!

Comment: @vsz it's the only Golf suitable language I know, it often beats most common langs :)

Answer (score 5):

### Brainf*ck (only 2 characters)

```
+.
```

Comment: Of course, I'll still accept a solution of length 2.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? It should output ASCII 1 which is a non-printable character.

Comment: @nyuszika7h : many consoles output a smiley for ASCII 1.

Comment: Really? I've never seen such a console. I bet they use some obscure charset.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't beat 2 chars, but:

### **PHP 11 chars.**

```
<?=chr(1)?>
```

---

For everyone saying you can simply place the smiley in php and it will output `☺`:

Running it with php.exe in the command line gives `Γÿǁ` and placing it in the browser gives `â˜º`

It does **not** work.

Comment: You could also go the HTML route that m0nhawk did.

Comment: @GigaWatt You cannot. It puts out gibberish using PHP. Did you even try? I tried it in the CLI and the browser.

Comment: Works fine for me.  http://ideone.com/6wYzx9

Comment: Running it with php.exe in the command line gives `Γÿǁ` and placing it in the browser gives `â˜º`

Comment: If you do a hex dump of your file, you'll see that it was saved as unicode representation of a smiley (`\xE298BA`), not as `\x01`.  Try manually making a file with a single `\x01` byte in it and running it from the command line with PHP.

Answer (score 5):

## DC - 2 characters

```
1P
```

It doesn't require any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

#### Golfscript, 3 characters

```
"☺"
```

Not a golfscript expert, but I don't believe there is a way to convert an integer into the corresponding ASCII character using only 1 character, so it seems like this is the shortest it can get

Answer (score 4):

## PHP (1)

```
☺
```

Technically this is a valid PHP file (a web server will happily serve it).

Answer (score 3):

## LaTeX (51/77 characters)

Short solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
☺
\end{document}
```

Good solution (Compile with `latex main.tex`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\smiley
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first one does not work because pure LaTeX cannot read unicode chars. Oddly enough, this does not work neither in XeLaTeX, nor in LuaLaTeX because the default font table does not contain this symbol. Please consider this: `\documentclass{book} \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{DejaVu Sans} \begin{document}☺\end{document}` — and please specify the rendering engine you are using (pdfLaTeX) in the “good” solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Q/k (9 chars)

Can't do it in 2 unfortunately.

```
-1"\001";
```

I seem to recall a bug in an older version of the interpreter which produced the other smile symbol in less characters. I'll look it up.

Edit: found the quirk. It only appears to work on windows versions of the interpreter:

```
q)1(1b);
☺
```

Answer (score 2):

## J (3 chars)

```
'☺'
```

The code require appropriate font.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J)

> In the Wingdings font, the letter "J" is rendered as a smiley face (note this is distinct from the Unicode code point U+263A, which renders as ☺).

Comment: Another variation is `u:1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 9 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZOLk0tB4f9/AA)

```
ssstl   push 1 on stack
tlss    output char
```

Answer (score 1):

## Burlesque - 6 Characters

`,1L[sh`

Explanation:

`,` pops stdin. `1L[` pushes one and convert to char (by codepoint) `sh` is used to switch to pretty format. (Otherwise it would print a leading `'`).

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 1

```
☺
```

Displays a ☺ with some other stuff.
There are rumors that this also works with PHP or other languages.

Answer (score 1):

### Arduino, 24

```
char a=1;Serial.print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
1]
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=1]&i=)

Comment: The Stax `]` doesn't work prefixly - it pops an item from the stack and creates a list from it. So you might alternatively need [`1]`](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=1]&i=) for the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 characters

Push the number 1 and print it. (Surprised that `1,` also works; -1 from Lyxal.)

```
1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/xlDn/38A)

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 character

Keg is actually Turing-complete, and any unrecognized command acts as a push onto the stack.

```
☺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0Yxd//8DAA)

Comment: It's actually `1,` making it 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 characters

Just a boring hard-coding. It's encoded in CP437.

```
"☺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f6dGMXf//AwA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
1ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8PDy//8B)

Comment: You may want to include the encodings. Your top answer is only 2 bytes in an encoding like CP850 or CP437, which contains both the characters `☺` and `"` in their codepage. But using the 05AB1E encoding, the top answer isn't even possible, and using the UTF-8 encoding it would be 4 bytes.

Comment: The challenge says that characters are a valid encoding system...

Answer (score 1):

## [chevron](https://ch.superloach.xyz/?inp=&src=PuKYug%3D%3D) - 4 bytes/2 runes

```
>☺
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6 (7 chars)

```
say '☺'
```

I'm bending the rules a little by assuming that a \n is welcome to avoid shell prompt mess.

Comment: Are you sure you need that space character?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 10 Bytes

```
alert("☺")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 3 characters

```
?"☺
```

​​

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 5 bytes

if a program should output the smile face char.

```powershell
'☺'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X/3RjF3q//8DAA)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 7 bytes

if a program should output the char with code 1.

```powershell
[char]1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Pzo5I7Eo1vD/fwA)

Comment: Why not just `'☺'` ? By the way, the face isn't rendered for me in TIO or the console

Comment: because the code for the smile face is not 1 in the Powershell. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P9o5P68stagk1sqqJN8zr8TMREP90Yxd6tEGsZr//wMA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Should your answer be '[Char]9786' instead then? I'm really confused :-D

Comment: Ha! You are right. I thought I'd write a program that outputs a character with code 1. But you can interpret it as writing a program that outputs a smiley face.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 2 bytes

```
1H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39Dj/38A)

Just for completeness. Push a single 1, print all the contents as characters and halt.

Answer (score 0):

## [MineFriff](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Minefriff), 5 bytes

```
C1,o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83MS00rykxL@//f2VAn3/r/fwA)

Simply:

- Treat the temp register as a character
- Add one to the register and push
- Output the top item and finish.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 15 bytes

```c
f(){puts("☺");}
```

☺

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oLSkWEPp0YxdSprWtf8z80oUchMz8zTK8jNTNLmquRSAAKjMmqv2PwA)