# Print a smiley face

Tags: ascii-art, popularity-contest

**Requirements**

For the sake of the challenge let's define a *unit*:

> A unit is defined as any point that compose the grid in which the face is drawn (pixels for screen, characters for ASCII art, etc..).

The *minimal requirements* for the face are:

> A smiley face is composed of a  shape that resemble a circle (not necessarily perfect) of any radius. There must be at least 1 unit for each of the two eyes and at least 2 units for the mouth. Both eyes and mouth should be within the face shape. The mouth can be oriented however you want (happy, sad, indifferent, etc..).

Here's an example of the output:

```
 0 0 0    . . .
0 . . 0  . o o .
0 --- 0  . \_/ .
 0 0 0    . . .
```

**Goals**

Of course the main goal is to come up with the shortest code possible, but *art* is also important.

**Winner**

The winner is chosen based on the amount of votes from the users, in, at least, the next 5 days.

Comment: Similar: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8932/smile-just-smile/8970#8970

Comment: Wow, 8 questions on the hot question list. Our site should be getting more traffic.

Comment: Isn't indifferent face strictly easier than happy, and sad sometimes more difficult?

Comment: Not going to make this an answer since it doesn't fit the minimum requirements, but I wanted to chime in... `alt + 1` and `alt + 2` will produce ☺ and ☻ respectively. For the sake of argument I'll consider the `alt` key press a character and call that 2 characters.

Comment: Javascript Bookmarklet: `javascript:b=document.body;b.innerHTML='<font size="200">&#9785;'` (Posted here as this post is now protected)

Comment: Will this thread ever end? :)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

### Javascript, 340

```js
var i=0,b=document.body,d=20,n=b.clientWidth,m=b.clientHeight,f="width=10,height=10,"
var o=new Function("f","i","t",'open("","",f+"left="+i+",top="+t)')
for(j=0;j<m/d;++j,i=j*d){
   u=Math.sqrt(i*(m-i))
   t=m/2+u*(j%2-0.5)*2
   o(f,i,t)
   i>m/5&&i<0.8*m&&j%2&&o(f,i,t-m/4);
   ((i<m/3&&i>m/4)||(i<3*m/4&&i>2*m/3))&&o(f,i,m/3)
}
```

---

### Javascript, 283

**optimized version (with some improvements & without unnecessary white spaces)**

```
var i=0,b=document.body,d=20,n=b.clientWidth,m=b.clientHeight,f="width=10,height=10,"
function o(i,t){open("","",f+"left="+i+",top="+t)}for(j=0;j<m/d;i=++j*d){u=Math.sqrt(i*(m-i));t=m/2+j%2*2*u-u;o(i,t);i>m/5&&i<0.8*m&&j%2&&o(i,t-m/4);((i<m/3&&i>m/4)||(i<3*m/4&&i>2*m/3))&&o(i,m/3)}
```

Well.. maybe it isn't as short as you would want to but it's unconventional for sure. It looks better when your browser is maximized. I really enjoyed your question!
If you want to increase the details just reduce `d` variable slightly.

edit: Unfortunately I can't run it on jsfiddle <s>but you can paste it to Javascript console in aby browser. Oh, and enable popups on the page :).</s>

**edit2:** 
You can run it making a new html file and paste the code into it:

```
<body>
<script>
var i=0,b=document.body,d=20,n=b.clientWidth,m=b.clientHeight,f="width=10,height=10,"
var o=new Function("f","i","t",'open("","",f+"left="+i+",top="+t)')
for(j=0;j<m/d;++j,i=j*d){
   u=Math.sqrt(i*(m-i))
   t=m/2+u*(j%2-0.5)*2
   o(f,i,t)
   i>m/5&&i<0.8*m&&j%2&&o(f,i,t-m/4);
   ((i<m/3&&i>m/4)||(i<3*m/4&&i>2*m/3))&&o(f,i,m/3)
}
</script>
</body>
```

Then when you run it and nothing happens, just enable the popup windows and reload the page.
In addition I paste
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see nothing. Do you have a live demo? (like jsfiddle)

Comment: please see edit

Comment: whoa, that's a lot of popups. Sadly, I can't see the whole thing... Could you upload a screenshot please? (and congrats for the unconventional approach!)

Comment: Really original, I like it.

Comment: In the name of Bwian of Judea, what is this...

Comment: it's more like Santa..

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @the_Seppi : code relies on the popups so disable popup blockers, adBlock & related stuff, then refresh your html file in a browser.

Comment: popups enabled, need them for js debugging, ABP disabled on jsfiddle, still not working (Im using Chromium browser)

Comment: You won't run it on jsfiddle. I tried and I failed. Make a new html file locally and insert the code I pasted in my answer. It should work well.

Comment: Now it's working. Took me about 2m to close all popups

Comment: @the_Seppi, right click, close all windows?

Comment: After spending so much time trying to disable annoying popups, enabling them is hard. I disabled adBLock and allowed all popups in my browser...after half the face appears, it decides to turn the blocker back on!

Comment: Worderful answer!

Comment: Amazing out-of-the-box thought! I would never think to do something like this.

Comment: That's outstandingly original!

Comment: It even looks 3D!

Answer (score 69):

## HTML, <s>200</s> 141 characters

Thanks to [avail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11887/avall), I've cut this down to [141 characters](http://jsfiddle.net/TdPkF/6/):

```
<fieldset><legend>\\\\\\\\\\\\ ////</legend><center><input size=1 value=o> <input size=1 value=o /><br><input type=radio><br><button>........
```

Here's the original HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>\\\\\\\\\\\\ ////</legend>
<center><input type=text size=1 value=o />
<input type=text size=1 value=o /><br/>
<input type=radio /><br/>
<button>........</button></center></fieldset>
```

[Works best on small screens:](http://jsfiddle.net/R69Tw/)

[image: :-|]

Comment: This is *art* :P

Comment: You don't have to close most of your tags (most browsers will handle it), you don't need to define the type of input (text is default) and don't close <br> (html5). Here's the optimised code with only 150 chars :): http://jsfiddle.net/avall/TdPkF/

Comment: 158 chars and now centers the hair so it looks good on any size screen. http://jsfiddle.net/TdPkF/5/

Comment: @AverageMarcus It can be `align=center` instead of `style=text-align:center` in `<legend>` tag so 11 characters less :)

Comment: @avall That made me come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/TdPkF/8/ at 111 chars (no hair but better on all displays)

Comment: 1   qCSV** 7cg6f Qhy baCSrb c

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You should remove all but 3 of the hairs, and then it would be Homer Simpson!

Answer (score 56):

## Brainfuck: 583 characters (without counting whitespace)

```
 >>------>->->+++++>->->---->>>>------>>>>
 >>>>---->->------->>->->->---->>-------->
 ->->------>>>>>>>>>>-->---->>-->---->>->
  -->>>------>>>>>>>>->---->---->>->->->-
  >>->---->---->>++++[-<++++>]<[-<++++
  ++<++++++++<+++<++<++++++<++++++<++++++
 <++++++<++<++++++<++++++++<+++<++<++<++<++
<++<++<++<+<++<++++<++++++++<+++<++<+++<+++
<++<++++++   <++++++++<++++<    ++<++<++<++
<++<++<++<++<+<+++<++++++<+++<++<++++++<+++
+++<++++++<+++<++<++  +<++++++<++++++<++<++
 <++<++<++<++<++<+<++<++<++<++++++<++++++
  <++++++<+++++<++++++<+++<+>>>>>>>>>>>>
    >>>>>>                       >>>>>
     >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
          >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]<[.<]
```

**Output:**

```
\|/ ____ \|/       
 @~/ ,. \~@        
/_( \__/ )_\       
   \__U_/
```

Comment: The original code looks a bit like a face (if you try really hard...), I wonder how hard it would be to make the code and output both be faces...

Comment: @handuel Both are faces, but different. Did you mean the code and the output to be the same like a quine? I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: I just meant for the code to look more like a face, I didn't realize it was intentional.

Comment: In Brainfuck, everything that is not a control character is a comment. That is why the source code can be made to look like a smiley.

Answer (score 40):

## SVG

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="f" fx="25%" fy="25%" r="60%">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
            <stop offset="0.6" stop-color="#ff0"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f80"/>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle fill="url(#f)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" cx="100" cy="100" r="90"/>
    <ellipse cx="70" cy="70" rx="10" ry="20"/>
    <ellipse cx="130" cy="70" rx="10" ry="20"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" d="M 40 120 S 100 200 160 120"/>
</svg>
```

Renders like this:

[image: Smiley]

Comment: Infinite units?

Comment: The right tool for the right job.

Comment: I wouldn't say SVG is really a programming language

Comment: @Oliver It's as much a programming language as HTML is... (which it isn't).

Answer (score 38):

### Ruby, 224

Douglas Adams would be horrified. :-P

```
w=?$;"^XA[_AXeMFGIAHJLjKNAEFEJJNHQHNKLAEMINJOJOHLAGKHOJOJ[AG[HQHRFJAH}IH
IGGwIIAHHGwKHAHGHrEUAGQFiGVAGQGfIPAFHKHHbJHAQII]MGASHNSOHATIdIAUJJRLIAWLIQGK
ZOFUA]ZAeSAiPAjOAkL".codepoints{|r|r-=68;$><<(r<0??\n:(w=w==?$?' ':?$)*r)}
```

Output:

```
                          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                       $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$         $$   $$$$$
    $$$$$$        $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $$$$$$$$$$
 $$ $$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$       $$$$$$$$
 $$$$$$$$$     $$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$
   $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  $$$$$$
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$
     $$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$$
    $$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $$$$
    $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
   $$$$$$$$$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
   $$$$$$$$$$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$       $$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$
             $$$$$     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$         $$$
               $$$$          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$           $$$$
                $$$$$                                $$$$$
                 $$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$        $$$$$
                   $$$$$$$$     $$$$$$$$$$$$$   $$$$$$$
                      $$$$$$$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                         $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                                 $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                                     $$$$$$$$$$$$
                                      $$$$$$$$$$$
                                       $$$$$$$$
```

---

### Ruby, 110

Same technique. Less code. Less artful. Looks like someone melted a plastic smiley. :-}

```
w=?$;"TXANdAKQGZAHSI[AGaGRAFaIRAFPGeAGQJ_AHURQAJkANc
TX".codepoints{|r|r-=68;$><<(r<0??\n:(w=w==?$?' ':?$)*r)}
```

Output:

```
                $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
       $$$$$$$$$$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
   $$$$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$              $$$$$$$$$$$$$
      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

Comment: Does the second example count? There's no circle around the face.

Comment: @Kevin, good point. Amended.

Answer (score 24):

## QBasic ASCII, 134 (unoptimized)

```
SCREEN 1
PRINT CHR$(1)
FOR i = 0 TO 64
  x = i \ 8
  y = i MOD 8
  LOCATE y + 2, x + 1
  IF POINT(x, y) THEN PRINT "X"
NEXT
```

This answer totally cheats by using ASCII character 1 for its smiley. However, unlike the BF and "plain text" answers, it actually obeys the rules by making ASCII art based on the pixels of the smiley character, rather than just plainly printing the character as its full solution. The unoptimized version represents how QBasic's IDE saves the files. The IDE is "helpfully" fixing up the syntax for us and adding a lot of whitespace where "needed".

Output:
[image: QBasic ASCII smiley unoptimized]

## QBasic ASCII, 80 (optimized)

```
SCREEN 1
?"☺"
FOR i=0TO 64
x=i\8
y=i MOD 8
LOCATE y+2,x+1
?CHR$(POINT(x,y))
NEXT
```

This is an optimized version of the first code sample, which still loads in QBasic. Things that were done:

- Removed all unnecessary whitespace. (D'uh!)
- Changed the CRLF line breaks to LF only.
- Replaced `CHR$(1)` with a string containing the actual character. (Here illustrated with a matching Unicode character. If you actually want to try the code, please replace it with a real ASCII character 1 using a hex editor.)
- Replaced `PRINT` with `?`, as the BASIC tradition allows for.
- Replaced the `IF` line with a line that prints characters based on the source pixel value. This will be be either 0 or 3. 0 is the color black. Character 0 prints a null character which is treated like a space. 3 is the color white in CGA's 4-color palette. ASCII character 3 is a heart.

Output:
[image: QBasic ASCII smile optimized]

## QBasic graphical, 83 (whitespace optimized)

```
SCREEN 1
CIRCLE(50,50),50
CIRCLE(50,50),30,,4,5.4
CIRCLE(30,40),10
CIRCLE(70,40),10
```

But wait, I here you ask, can't you just use QBasic's built-in graphics commands? Sure, but that won't actually save you any bytes, because of the verbosity of the language. But it does have a built-in function to only draw a circle arc between two given angles, which is nice. The angles are given in radians, and `4` and `5.4` approximate a circle arc symmetrically centered around `π*3/2`, or if you've joined [the good side](http://tauday.com/), `τ*3/4`.

Output:
[image: QBasic graphical smiley optimized]

Note: The sizes in this answer denote how big the file is in, in bytes.

Comment: I feel that I may be the youngest person here who can still read QBASIC... :)  Nice one

Answer (score 12):

## APL, 97 chars/bytes*

```
(63⍴1 0)\' /%'[1+(12≥⊃+/¨2*⍨m+¨⊂6 ¯6)+((⍉18<(⍴n)⍴⍳32)∧28≥|100-n)+256≥n←⊃+/¨2*⍨m←x∘.,|x←¯16.5+⍳32]
```

It works by computing a few circle equations. Tested on [GNU APL](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/).

**Output**
[image: smiley output]
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Answer (score 11):

## Bash, 63 chars

```
echo $'$the_cow=""'>.cow;cowsay -f ./.cow $'O O\n\n\_/';rm .cow
```

Output:

```
 _____
/ O O \
|     |
\ \_/ /
 -----
```

Artistry:

Cows.

Answer (score 9):

## Bash, 22 chars

```
wget x.co/3WG0m -q -O-
```

Sample output:
[image]

Edit: this could be golfed further as suggested by several people.  The shortest self-contained version found so far is:

```
curl -L x.co/3WG0m
```

(thanks nitro2k01)

Comment: Could be optimized to `curl -L x.co/3WG0m`. Could be further optimized if we have a local, one-character hostname which also return the data directly (eliminating the `-L` switch needed to follow redirects.)

Comment: Where's the challange in posting a smiley in pastebin and downloading it using wget?

Comment: @the_Seppi: that's exactly the joke.  It's intended as a thinking-outside-the-box solution.

Comment: We need to find someone with access to the root nameservers and convince him to add a domain called `Z` that points to a server hosting the file.

Comment: beautiful, this is my favorite :)

Answer (score 9):

**Python <strike>247</strike>  <strike>230</strike> 227 Characters - and a cuter version**

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
from numpy import*
y=x=arange(-8,11,.1)
x,y=meshgrid(x,y)
contour(x,y,(x*x*(x**2+2*y*y-y-40)+y*y*(y*y-y-40)+25*y+393)*((x+3)**2+(y-5)**2-2)*((x-3)**2+(y-5)**2-2)*(x*x+(y-2)**2-64),[0])
show()
```

[image]

**Python 243 Characters - Using colors**

```
from pylab import*
from numpy import*
y=x=arange(-9,11,.1)
x,y=meshgrid(x,y)
contourf(x,y,(x*x*(x**2+2*y*y-y-40)+y*y*(y*y-y-40)+25*y+393)*((x+3)**2+(y-5)**2-2)*((x-3)**2+(y-5)**2-2)*(x*x+(y-2)**2-64),1,colors=("#F0E68C",'#20B2AA'))
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## C++ - 122 characters without unnecessary spaces

This is the most realistic I could come up with:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "  |||||\n 0 . . 0\n0   ^   0\n0  \\_/  0\n 0     0\n  00000\n   888\n    8\n\n";
}
```

For those of you who are missing out, it creates this:
[image: ASCII art image]

Comment: `return 0;` is not required in ISO C++ :)

Comment: Thanks.  That will help cut characters in future puzzles.

Answer (score 6):

```
cowsay -f calvin Hey, What´s up?
 _________________
< Hey, What´s up? >
 -----------------
 \                   .,
   \         .      .TR   d'
     \      k,l    .R.b  .t .Je
       \   .P q.   a|.b .f .Z%      
           .b .h  .E` # J: 2`     .
      .,.a .E  ,L.M'  ?:b `| ..J9!`.,
       q,.h.M`   `..,   ..,""` ..2"`
       .M, J8`   `:       `   3;
   .    Jk              ...,   `^7"90c.
    j,  ,!     .7"'`j,.|   .n.   ...
   j, 7'     .r`     4:      L   `...
  ..,m.      J`    ..,|..    J`  7TWi
  ..JJ,.:    %    oo      ,. ....,
    .,E      3     7`g.M:    P  41
   JT7"'      O.   .J,;     ``  V"7N.
   G.           ""Q+  .Zu.,!`      Z`
   .9.. .         J&..J!       .  ,:
      7"9a                    JM"!
         .5J.     ..        ..F`
            78a..   `    ..2'
                J9Ksaw0"'
               .EJ?A...a.
               q...g...gi
              .m...qa..,y:
              .HQFNB&...mm
               ,Z|,m.a.,dp
            .,?f` ,E?:"^7b
            `A| . .F^^7'^4,
             .MMMMMMMMMMMQzna,
         ...f"A.JdT     J:    Jp,
          `JNa..........A....af`
               `^^^^^'`
```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, many other languages... - 1601 characters

```
                          oooo$$$$$$$$$$$$oooo
                      oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o
                   oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o         o$   $$ o$
   o $ oo        o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o       $$ $$ $$o$
oo $ $ "$      o$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$o       $$$o$$o$
"$$$$$$o$     o$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$o    $$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  """$$$
   "$$$""""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     "$$$
    $$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     "$$$o
   o$$"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $$$o
   $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" "$$$$$$ooooo$$$$o
  o$$$oooo$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$"$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$""""""""
 """"       $$$$    "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"      o$$$
            "$$$o     """$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$"         $$$
              $$$o          "$$""$$$$$$""""           o$$$
               $$$$o                                o$$$"
                "$$$$o      o$$$$$$o"$$$$o        o$$$$
                  "$$$$$oo     ""$$$$o$$$$$o   o$$$$""
                     ""$$$$$oooo  "$$$o$$$$$$$$$"""
                        ""$$$$$$$oo $$$$$$$$$$
                                """"$$$$$$$$$$$
                                    $$$$$$$$$$$$
                                     $$$$$$$$$$"
                                      "$$$""
```

Smiley source: [Asciiworld.com : Smiley](http://www.asciiworld.com/-Smiley,20-.html)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript <strike>262</strike> 251

**Edit:** added better eyes.

Prints a smiley face into the console.

Could lose quite a few characters to make my bitmask simpler and print a less pretty face, or use a circle equation instead of an ellipse to account for character spacing - but that's not the spirit.

You can change the `r` variable to change the size and get a more or less detailed face; any number `>=7 && <=99` will give a good result and stay within the character limit.

```
function c(e,t,n){return t/2*Math.sqrt(1-e*e/(n*n))+.5|0}r=42;p=r/2;q=p/5;s="";for(y=-p;++y<p;){for(x=-r;++x<r;){d=c(y,r*2,p);e=c(y+q,r/5,q);f=e-p;g=e+p;h=c(y,r*1.3,r/3);s+=x>=d||x<=-d||x>=-g&&x<f||x<=g&&x>-f||y>q&&x>-h&&x<h?" ":0}s+="\n"}console.log(s)
```

Human readable:

```
function c(y,w,h){return w/2*Math.sqrt(1-y*y/(h*h))+0.5|0}
r = 42
p = r/2
q = p/5
s = ''
for (y = -p; ++y < p;) {
  for (x = -r; ++x < r;) {
    d = c(y,r*2,p)
    e = c(y+q,r/5,q)
    f = e - p
    g = e + p
    h = c(y,r*1.3,r/3)
    s+=(x>=d||x<=-d||(x>-g&&x<f)||(x<g&&x>-f)||(y>q&&(x>-h&&x<h)))?' ':0
  }
  s += '\n'
}
console.log(s)
```

**Output:**

[image: smiley in console]

My first game of golf so likely to be some improvements.

Answer (score 4):

### html, css

I know it's neither short nor real coding, but I still wanted to post this

```
<head>
<style>

#a{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50px;
border: 1px solid black; 
}
#b{
position: absolute;
top:30px;
left:30px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#c{
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:40px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
}#d{
position: absolute;
top:30px;
left:-30px;
width:40px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a">
<div id="b"/>
<div id="c"/>
<div id="d"/>
</div>
</body>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97pCv/)

Comment: Maybe would look better with `#d{border-radius:20px/10px;}`. Or with `#d{border-radius:0 0 20px 20px/0 0 10px 10px;}`. Or with `#d{height:10px;border-radius:0 0 20px 20px/0 0 10px 10px;margin-top:10px;}`.

Answer (score 4):

### [Rebmu](http://hostilefork.com/rebmu/), 24 chars

Oh, the [m-i-n-i-m-a-l](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ywk3vA8Y8xY) humanity.  :-)  Least impressive Rebmu program yet, so purposefully embedding pHp as a tribute to [the blue pill in the programming world](http://www.php.net/manual/en/images/c0d23d2d6769e53e24a1b3136c064577-php_logo.png):

`H{ -- }pHp{|..|^/|\/|}pH`

**Execution:**

```
>> rebmu [H{ -- }pHp{|..|^/|\/|}pH]
 -- 
|..|
|\/|
 --
```

**Explanation**

Rebmu is just a dialect of [Rebol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebol).  It inherits the parse constraints, uses abbreviated terms without spaces separated by runs of capitalization.  It has a special treatment when the first run is capitalized vs uncapitalized.

*(So rather than separating terms like `AbcDefGhi` it can use the difference between `ABCdefGHI` and `abcDEFghi` to squeeze out a bit of information.  Sequences whose runs start in all capitalized are separated so the first term represents a "set-word!", often contextually interpreted as a desire for an assignment.  [see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDKaz1iB9wQ))*

If you want to translate this to native Rebol, you have to accept things like that it starts with a capital H to mean that's actually an `h:` and not an `h`.  The source is thus analogous to:

```
h: { -- }
print h
print {|..|^/|\/|}
print h
```

Assigns the string `--` to h (using asymmetric string delimiters because `print {"Isn't it nice," said {Dr. Rebmu}, "when you have asymmetric multi-line string delimiters with no need for escaping matched nested pairs, and that accept apostrophes and quotes too?"}`

Prints h once, prints another string where `^/` is the escape sequence for newline *(carets being less used in software than backslashes which appear often in paths)*, prints h again.

Answer (score 4):

**Perl, 106 chars**

It is a Perl oneliner, just have to C&P it on command prompt, provided the Perl `Acme::EyeDrops` module is already installed on the machine.

```
touch temp && perl -MAcme::EyeDrops='sightly' -e 'print sightly({Shape=>"smiley", SourceFile => "temp" } );'
```

[image]

Another way , a smiley with Pulling a face

```
     touch temp && perl -MAcme::EyeDrops='sightly' -e 'print sightly({Shape=>"smiley2",SourceFile=>"temp"});'
```

[image]

Yet another way,a smiley with Pulling a face upside down,

```
 touch temp && perl -MAcme::EyeDrops='sightly' -e 'print sightly({Shape=>"smiley2",SourceFile=>"temp",RotateFlip=>'true',Rotate=>'180'});'
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + ImageMagick: 137 characters

```bash
c=circle
convert -size 99x99 xc: -draw "fill #ff0 $c 49,49,49" -fill 0 -draw "$c 30,35,30,30 $c 70,35,70,30 ellipse 50,60,25,20,0,180" x:
```

Sample output:

[image: graphical smiley]

But as this is an [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) challenge…

## Bash + ImageMagick: 172 characters

```bash
d=-draw
p=-pointsize
convert -size 99x99 xc: -font times.ttf $p 140 -stroke 0 -fill \#ff0 $d 'text 0,96 O' $p 40 $d 'text 25,50 "o 0"' $p 50 $d 'rotate 95 text 50,-40 D' x:
```

Sample output:

[image: ASCII smiley]

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, 27

This outputs the 2nd example exactly as given.

```
' .'3*.'
. o o .
. \_/ .
'\
```

First one can be done the same way, but I think the 2nd one looks nicer :)

Answer (score 2):

## Brainf*** - 2

```
+.
```

Prints `☺` or ascii value 1. (might not work with some platforms)

Comment: Nitpick: ASCII 1 is SOH, a non-printable character. That smiley is U+263A, or 1 in CP437, what you are probably using. Unfortunately, your output fails the condition of using enough “units” for the eyes and mouth.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig It does not fail that condition. Each eye is 1 or so pixels, the mouth is more than twice as large.

Comment: The exp. "ASCII ART" consists of two parts. I see neither of them here

Answer (score 2):

## Bash - one liner: 442 characters

```
c(){ e "define a(i){scale=scale(i);return(sqrt(i*i));};""$@"|bc -l;};e(){ echo "$@";};s(){ h=$1;c=$2;if [ -z $c ];then c=" ";fi;while (($((h=h-1))>0));do e -n "$c"; done; };m(){ t=`c 2*$1`;while (($((t=t-1))));do l=`c a\($1-$t\)+1`;s $l;q=`c 2*\($1-$l\)`;w=`s $q`;if (($l>$t&&$l<($t+3)&&$q>2)); then w=" "`s $((q-2)) 0`" ";elif (($t>($1+1)&&$q>3));then g=`s $(((q-1)/2)) 0`;w=" $g $g ";fi;e -n +;if [ ! -z "$w" ];then e -n "$w+";fi;e;done;};
```

Example output: (called by `m 8`)

```
       +
      + +
     +   +
    + 0 0 +
   + 00 00 +
  + 000 000 +
 +           +
+             +
 +           +
  +         +
   +       +
    + 000 +
     +   +
      + +
       +
```

Kind of crazy, but I chose to use a diamond instead of a circle. The eyes are covered by safety goggles.

## BASH - 252 characters (thanks @manatwork)

```
s(){ (($1>1))&&echo -n "${2:- }"&&s $[$1-1] $2;};m(){ ((t=2*$1));while ((t=t-1));do v=$[$1-t];l=$[${v#-}+1];s $l;q=$[2*($1-l)];w=`s $q`;((l>t&&l<t+3&&q>2))&&w=" `s $[q-2] 0` ";((t>$1+1&&q>3))&&{ g=`s $[(q-1)/2] 0`;w=" $g $g ";};echo "+${w:+$w+}";done;}
```

Comment: Cool. With that shape it could replace my gravatar image. :) It can be reduced to 252 characters: `s(){ (($1>1))&&echo -n "${2:- }"&&s $[$1-1] $2;};m(){ ((t=2*$1));while ((t=t-1));do v=$[$1-t];l=$[${v#-}+1];s $l;q=$[2*($1-l)];w=\`s $q\`;((l>t&&l<t+3&&q>2))&&w=" \`s $[q-2] 0\` ";((t>$1+1&&q>3))&&{ g=\`s $[(q-1)/2] 0\`;w=" $g $g ";};echo "+${w:+$w+}";done;}`. Or 245 if you give up the function m and put the code in a script file. Probably can be reduced even more by tweaking the calculations, but I have no time for that now.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML + CSS, 83**

```
<div><a>o<a>o</a><hr><hr><style>a,div{width:2em;border:2px solid;border-radius:8px
```

screenshot(using firefox):
[image]

too bad that I'm too late with my answer
(got +10 rep also quite late ...)

Comment: I like it more with `border-radius:50%` and a single `<hr>`: http://dabblet.com/gist/8472397

Comment: @manatwork or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/1/

Comment: Since the face is so creepy: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/3/

Comment: @TimSeguine, using a literal non-breaking space character is shorter than `&nbsp;`: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/2/

Comment: Eyes overlapping the face is against the rules, I think. That's why I did it like it is currently. Also it kinda reminds me of the canadians face in south park.

Comment: Okay, no overlap: now it is even creepier. It looks like mr skullhead. http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/4/

Comment: mouth's units are also not allowed to overlap :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/6/

Comment: If you manage to do it without javascript, relying on css selectors and animations, i give you +1 :D

Comment: @TimSeguine, in this stage may worth “investing” in a `<center>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/7/

Comment: @LeoPflug I can't get it to work with `hr`s, I'd have to try something else.

Comment: Not really golfed, but as requested, a css only version: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BdL/9/

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 18

This program uses some binary-encoded values which appear as weird/invalid characters in a text editor.

Here's the hex dump:

```
00000000  27 c1 94 80 a2 9c c1 27  7b 32 62 61 73 65 20 70  |'......'{2base p|
00000010  7d 25                                             |}%|
```

Note: it doesn't work in a UTF-8 locale, but works fine with ISO-8859-1 for example.

The expanded version with escaped characters:

```
"\xc1\x94\x80\xa2\x9c\xc1"{2base p}%
```

Output:

```
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
[1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

For nicer output, you can replace the block with `{2base{38+}%n}` which brings the binary version to 23 bytes. Expanded version:

```
"\xc1\x94\x80\xa2\x9c\xc1"{2base{38+}%n}%
```

Output:

```
''&&&&&'
'&&'&'&&
'&&&&&&&
'&'&&&'&
'&&'''&&
''&&&&&'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
smileyFace = '''
       000000000000000
      00000000000000000
     000000   00   00000
    0000000 . 00 . 000000
   00000000   00   0000000
  0000000000000000000000000
 000000 . 00000000 . 0000000
  000000 . 000000 . 0000000
   0000000 ....... 0000000
    000000000000000000000
     0000000000000000000
      00000000000000000'''
print(smileyFace)
```

```
print('  _________\n /         \\\n |  /\\ /\\  |\n |    -    |\n |  \\___/  |\n \\_________/');
```

Output:

```
  _________
 /         \
 |  /\ /\  |
 |    -    |
 |  \___/  |
 \_________/
```

Comment: second example is missing the circle

Comment: @Jasen I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

This code must be run in `f12` on this page:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].innerHTML)
```

Output:

```
 0 0 0    . . .
0 . . 0  . o o .
0 --- 0  . \_/ .
 0 0 0    . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 18

I decided to go for short code... [Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

```
" ##O#- #"2/{_(N}%
```

### Explanation

```
" ##O#- #"      "Push a string onto the stack";
2/              "Split it into an array of two-character groups";
{_(N}%          "For each item in the array, execute _(N : duplicate the element,
                 remove the first character and place it onto the stack after what's left,
                 and push a new line.";
```

This exploits the symmetry of the smiley face I designed.

### Output

```
 ## 
#OO#
#--#
 ##
```

Comment: This face it not smiling ;).

Comment: @Optimizer It's closer to a smile than [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18707/16402)... Because of how I've used symmetry, you can't have a smile here.

Comment: Using `uu` for the smile is an option, if you're going for that "cat" kind of smile...

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript console

a frog:

```
prompt("◉◉ ", ' '.repeat(25)+"⊂(‿)つ")
```

table flip

```
prompt("┻━┻", ' '.repeat(24)+"ʕノ•ᴥ•ʔノ")
```

and i am not sure what this one is

```
prompt('◕  '.repeat(24),prompt("◕              ◕", '  ▇  '.repeat(24)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 42

```
print ' 0 0 0 \n0 . . 0\n0 --- 0\n 0 0 0 '
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 : 321 Characters

```
<canvas id=a><script>_=document.getElementById("a"),c=_.getContext("2d"),p=Math.PI,P=2*p;C();c.arc(95,85,40,0,P);B();c.lineWidth=2;c.stroke();c.fillStyle="red";C();c.arc(75,75,5,0,P);B();C();c.arc(114,75,5,0,P);B();C();c.arc(95,90,26,p,P,true);B();function C(){c.beginPath()};function B(){c.closePath();c.fill()}</script>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wfNGx/

[image]

Source : http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-SWM11/0/1

Answer (score 0):

## Shell command or builtin

```
$ echo -e ' ,---.\n/ o o \\\n\ \\_/ /\n `---´'
 ,---.
/ o o \
\ \_/ /
 `---´
$ printf ' ,---.\n/ o o \\\n\ \\_/ /\n `---´\n'
 ,---.
/ o o \
\ \_/ /
 `---´
```

Depending on the flavour of your shell or command set, `echo` may or may not interprete control characters with or witout `-e`... (...and I demand that I may or may not be Vroomfondel!) just try... and if all else fails, using `printf` should be a safe bet...

Answer (score 0):

### C 178 characters:

source (whitespace added - all can be removed except at `int x`

```
int x,y;
c(a,b,r)
{
  return  (x-a)*(x-a) + (y-b)*(y-b) < r*r;
}

main()
{
  for(x=9;x>=-9;--x)
  {
     for(y=-9;y<=9;++y)
       putchar(32<<(
         c(0,0,10)&&!(c(4,4,2)|c(4,-4,2)|c(3,0,8)&!c(7,0,10))
       ));
     putchar(10);}
 }
```

output:

```
     @@@@@@@@@
    @@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@   @@@@@   @@@
@@@@   @@@@@   @@@@
@@@@   @@@@@   @@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@ @@@
@@@  @@@@@@@@@  @@@
@@@@           @@@@
@@@@@@       @@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @@@@@@@@@@@
     @@@@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL, 628

For SQL Server 2012+

This is a query I did some time ago as a bit of fun and to show my kids.
It uses the string in @ to determine a few parameters B = base, O = offset, M = multiplier, D = divisor.  These are then used to create a SQL Server Geometry (2012+).

It's not particularly golfed.

```
DECLARE @ varchar(30)='Don''t Worry, Be Happy';
WITH P AS(
    SELECT LEN(PARSENAME(F,1))D,
        LEN(PARSENAME(F,2))M,
        LEN(PARSENAME(F,3))B,
        LEN(PARSENAME(F,4))O
    FROM (VALUES(REPLACE(@,' ','.')))S(F)
    )
SELECT @, Geometry::Point(B*M,B*M,0).STBuffer(B*M).STDifference((
    SELECT Geometry::UnionAggregate(g)
    FROM (
        SELECT Geometry::Point(B*M-O,B*M+O,0).STBuffer(B/D*M)FROM P
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Geometry::Point(B*M+O,B*M+O,0).STBuffer(B/D*M)FROM P
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Geometry::STGeomFromText(
            CONCAT('CIRCULARSTRING(', 
                B*M-O,' ',B*M-O,',',
                B*M,' ',(B*M-O)-((B*M)/(B*M-O)),',',
                B*M+O,' ',B*M-O,')'),0).STBuffer(B/D)FROM P
            )A(G)
        )) 
FROM P
```

When run in SSMS it shows the following in the spatial results tab
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 857 bytes

Just some idle obfuscation.

```
un="̤̤Ո͈̤ՇՇ̤͆F͆Ë̠̠́̈́ ՃC̠B̠͂ՁՁ̠Հ@ ̿̿Ԡ̾͜ծ̽̽>̼͂̾̾Ի̽;͂Ժͅ$Թ̹͈8՜̢77Շ̶Է̷̵554̓ͯ3oͯԲHͯ18̤̰0̰/ͣoͮͳol̮ͥլ̨ͯͧՠ̻Ծ̈́22̰ԲԲԺD2/ͯԽ̻̲̓/F1@̳̤C͈̠o̤̽Գ $̠2́3̯0ͯ?HԠ͈̠1̤̽2 ̤ ̤̠7̤̳̓9̰̤͂BFG̱?Ԥ1̱̤̽6$Ա̤̈́3Թ̸̱̀̀͂ͅՅ=DF͇B̸Հ̸@̰Ը≠̰̈́B0$Ղ0Ḧ̵̶́̽̓64/̯̤A̶=Ղ͇3/̯͈A̷̤1Խ̳͈7Ճ/ԯ͇̤̿Ա=C͇B/̰̹Է ̶$̱2̲H1Խ̈́o$1̲̤ͯ͆Dԯ̰$̳̰Ն̤̽Dͅ6$Cԯ9$A̴̴̴̠͆̽Կ͆͂7̯F7̓3G̼7̤̱́57԰ՆՈ̷H̷> ͇<D̤1̾̈́7H5FH4Ծ̳͇<̓H̱̻̠2̳͇̾̈́7̻̽7H̱C3͆17͈1̳̻́͆̽̈́Զ1ͯ́5HԱG̱3̵̺͆̈́ 5G̱̲oD7̤1̹57̺͂5͆$1oԠ̹̤?:>B4̸̾Ժ̻̰̿Ժ̻̠9̷̤̺̀ԻD̶4=͠ԩ",ㅤㅤㅤ=window;for(ㅤ in {escape:ㅤㅤ="un"})for(_=ㅤㅤㅤ[`${ㅤㅤ}${ㅤ}`](ㅤㅤㅤ[ㅤ](un).replace(/u../g,[]));__=/[/-H]/.exec(_);)with(_.split(__ ))_=join(shift());setTimeout(_,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page)/MetaPost (<s>104</s> 89 bytes)

This is a rather minimalistic smiley and you need at least 1000% zoom to see that poker face:

```tex
\startMPpage
let D=draw;D fullcircle scaled 5;D left;D right;D(-1,-1)--(1,-1)
\stopMPpage
```

[image]

[You can compile the document here as a PDF](https://live.contextgarden.net/)