# Create a program that output's itself as a series of punch cards

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

Create a program that output's itself as a series of punch cards:

[image: Computer Punch Card from the 70s]

**Rules:**

- You can use any programming language.
- The output (i.e. punch cards) can be ASCII art.
- Each line of code must be able to be punched into a single 80 column x 9 row punch card - i.e. you can only use 80 characters.
- To fit in the 9 rows you need to encode your characters using 4-bit BCD.
- Extra kudos if you use an old programming language like FORTRAN.

**Background**

- You can find out more about computer punch cards [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card).
- Doug Jones paper on [punch card codes](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/cards/codes.html).

Comment: This is very underspecified (especially for people too young to have used punch cards). What qualifies a line to fit on a punch card? What's a face-like image? And what is your scoring mechanism (you've included 3 different tags which imply different winning criteria).

Comment: sorry, very green here. I'll add more detail

Comment: Knowing exactly how many bytes can fit on a card would be helpful. You should remove the code golf tag if you want the votes to be the score. There is already a [smiley face](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16587/shortest-code-to-print-a-smiley-face) challenge so you may want to think of something new.

Comment: is this code-golf or popularity-contest? it can't be both. If it's popularity-contest its a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16587/15599 and if it's code-golf the shortest answer is print":)". Vogel, welcome to code golf. I fear this question cannot be saved. Writing a good question is hard. Please take a look around answer a few questions, and feel free to post your next question at http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1847/15599 if you would like the community to help you polish it before posting.

Comment: I've edited the question. Does that help?

Comment: I don't think that's technologically possible.

Comment: @Vogel The question has reopened. Is ASCII art valid output or do you only want an image file?

Comment: ASCII art is a valid output.

Comment: I agree with @B1KMusic .  I managed to get 116 in perl but for just the card (first 6 lines blank, alternating rows show punch numbers, other half are blank unless they're the two with character numbers.  While I'm sure I could *maybe* under 80 refining it, printing the text and properly knocking it out in EBCDIC encoding would blow virtually any language well over 80...

Comment: Actually, you know what would make this doable and cooler?  Have a program output itself as a series of punchcards.

Comment: I think you guys are right, it may be too hard to achieve the objective in 80 characters. @guifa that's a great idea, let me edit the puzzle.

Comment: @Vogel I added a golfed version. I was hoping that the ungolfed version would tempt a few other entries.

Comment: @ScottLeadley thanks man. Looks like you're the only one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ruby - 925

I'll get the ball rolling. Run as "ruby hammer.rb hammer.rb".

Golfed

```
def z x
l=x.unpack u='C*'
d=[]
(0..9).each do|i|d<<[].fill(48+i,0,80);end
d<<a=[].fill(32,0,80)
d<<a.dup
h=Hash.new
i=0;' abcdefghi'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c-32]=[i,11];h[c]=[i,11,0];i+=1;end
i=0;' jklmnopqr'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c-32]=[i,10];h[c]=[i,10,11];i+=1;end
i=0;'  stuvwxyz'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c-32]=[i,0];h[c]=[i,0,10];i+=1;end
h[47]=[1,0]
i=0;'0123456789-&'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c]=[i];i+=1;end
i=0;'  :#@\'="'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c]=[i,8];i+=1;end
i=0;'  [.<(+|'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c]=[i,8,11];i+=1;end
i=0;'  ]$*);^'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c]=[i,8,10];i+=1;end
i=0;'  \,%_>?'.unpack(u).each do|c|h[c]=[i,8,0];i+=1;end
h[32]=[]
i=0;l.slice(0,80).each do|c|h[c].each do|r|d[r][i]=215;end;i+=1;end
puts'    %s'%('_'*81)
puts'   /%-80s |'%l.pack(u)
puts'  / %s |'%d[11].pack(u)
puts' /  %s |'%d[10].pack(u)
(0..9).each do|i|puts'|   %s |'%d[i].pack(u);end
puts'|%s|'%('_'*84)
end
ARGF.each do|l|z l.chop;end
```

Ungolfed

```
def punch029(line) # line is array of ASCII characters in ordinal (integer) form
  chad=[]
  (0..9).each do |i| chad<<[].fill(48+i,0,80) end
  chad<<[].fill(32,0,80)
  chad<<[].fill(32,0,80)

  r10 = 10-10
  r11 = 11-1
  r12 = 12-1
  # Reward "bad" input characters with all-row multi-punch.
  # hash = Hash.new( [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] )
  #
  #   OR
  #
  # Reward "bad" input characters by letting Ruby puke. (Jam the machine.)
  hash = Hash.new
  '0123456789-&'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i] end
  ' ABCDEFGHI'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,r12] end
  ' JKLMNOPQR'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,r11] end
  ' /STUVWXYZ'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,r10] end
  '  :#@\'="'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,8] end
  '  [.<(+|'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,8,r12] end
  '  ]$*);^'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,8,r11] end
  '  \,%_>?'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,8,r10] end
  ' abcdefghi'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,r12,r10] end
  ' jklmnopqr'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,r11,r12] end
  '  stuvwxyz'.unpack('C*').each_with_index do|c,i| hash[c]=[i,r10,r11] end
  hash[32] = []              # fix space

  hole = 215
  line.slice(0,80).each_with_index do |c, index|
    hash[c].each do |row| chad[row][index] = hole end
  end

  puts '    %s' % ('_'*81)
  puts '   /%-80s |' % line.pack('C*')
  puts '  / %s |' % chad[11].pack('C*')
  puts ' /  %s |' % chad[10].pack('C*')
  (0..9).each do |i|
    puts '|   %s |' % chad[i].pack('C*')
  end
  puts "|%s|" % ('_'*84)
end
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

ARGF.each do |line|
  punch029(line.chomp.unpack('C*'))
end
```

Comment: The requirements aren't clear, e.g. BCD isn't 4 bit and lowercase can be created with the multi-punch key, so I decided that any character a 026/029 punch could encode was fine.